# Can monsters/bandits spawn in my house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I've just built my very first house (Heartfire DLC). I went downstairs and I had to fight 5 skeevers.
Will they respawn? Can bandits vandalise my house/stables/etc.? Can a follower stay there forever and take care of those circumstances?

Answer (score 6):

I never had mobs spawn in my house, but I regularly had thieves, giants and other nuisances right outside of my home.

And neither my housecarl nor anyone else took care of them. My assumption is that they do not spawn unless you are there.

The skeevers are an exception to appear as a house pest in the cellar. You wive might alert you that she heard something. You can also keep one of them as a pet if you have kids.

Comment: Really?! Kids playing with skeevers? Don't they know skeevers are not dogs?

Comment: @user26147 "*Don't they know skeevers are not dogs?*" Tell that to [Arvena Thelas](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Arvena_Thelas).

Comment: Yep. Mob spawning location isn't random; it's controlled by mob spawner nodes built into the landscape and buildings. (And yes, they only activate when the player is nearby.) There are none inside the house apart from the skeever one, so you'll never have bandits chewing your cellar barrels looking for grain, only rats.

Comment: I am frequently entertained by having bandits spawn inside the structure of my house when I fast travel to it.  I hear them yelling.  I walk around the house & the little red dots on my compass are always inside it.  I frequently need to step into & back out of my house to free them from their house shaped prison...

Answer (score -1):

In fact, bandits have spawned inside my house. And giants, wolves and bandits outside. I don't know if it's a glitch or something, but the answer to the question is a solid YES.

Answer (score -1):

I Believe monsters can't spawn inside your house, Unless they are skeevers, but bandits and such can, As in they can raid your things or attack you.
I have had it happen to me before but I believe it is very rare.